# Liquid - get product ID and display custom/specific information dynamically

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am trying to add a small 'lockup' / promo to a page that loads information dynamically based on page.metafield information. Replacing images, video ID's etc. Which all works just fine.

My client is asking for a small area to display a product that relates to this dynamically changing content and I am struggling to come up with a good way to do this.

The current setup is that we have 30 pages with a set of 8 metafields each page. Each one of these pages must show a different , single product with an image, title, price, buy button and another button that links out to a partner site.

I can create snippet and load almost all of this info through metafields manually (price, title etc the client could just add to another metafield) but I would prefer to load a product to pull this info so it can be added to cart. Although I can add product data manually, I still don't actually know which product will get added to the cart, because I'm on a 'page' not a 'product'.

The products themselves are using a custom template that is different to the rest of the site so that seems like its not an option. The template for this content page is just 'page' but surely I can call the product object someway? If the client entered a product ID in the metafields, is there a way of pulling that IDs data easily?

Comment: You need to add the product handle instead of ID into metafield, then you can get the product data using liquid code.

Comment: Care to elaborate some more?
I considered looping through all products within that collection and then comparing the ID/handle in the metafield to those in the loop.

Thats where I'm stuck though -if I loop through and find matches for ID / handle, does just adding something like <img src="{{product.image | img_url: '150x' }}">  or {{ product.price}} output the matching products image / price?

Comment: Instead of looping over all products, use `all_products` global object with a handle to get the data from Shopify end, read more about it [here](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#all_products)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you mean by pulling ID's, but there are a couple of ways of dealing with this. One, you have a Storefront API token, allowing you to freely and securely call Shopify with JS and get back all the data about the ID you're interested in. Or, you have an App installed in the store, in which case you can setup and callback an App Proxy, providing that ID, and getting back all the info you need. Lots of options!

Comment: Thanks - so there is no way of adding essentially a mini product page to another page just via Liquid then?

I'm basically trying to achieve what the "Buy Button" channel does but just have it in a tiny block with only certain information showing, based on that pages metafield data.

IDK if an image helps explain it? https://nimb.ws/89Fc5J

Comment: There is nothing dynamic about blocks. If you make up something that seems dynamic then great! You're good to go. You have to define what dynamic really means

Comment: Yeah, I definitely feel like I'm cheating, the main problem is the Add to Cart button.

So I have 30 pages with the same set of metafields with different data (image_asset_urls's, text, Vimeo ID's). Thats the dynamic part.

This little promo section is meant to allow someone to buy a product, but I cant see a way of actually loading 'a product' here to buy it.

Cant make this page a product template either (already used for the real product). The Buy button introduces a 2nd cart, detached from the sites actual cart too so thats out.